# Lex.DB Wack test failed

Tags: c#, api, windows-8.1

I am using lex.db in my windows store application , I ran Wack test and seems like if gets failed due to lex.db

> Supported API test
>
> FAILED
> Supported APIs
> Error Found: The supported APIs test detected the following errors:
> API GetFileAttributesW in kernel32.dll is not supported for this application type. Lex.Db.dll calls this API.
> API MoveFileW in kernel32.dll is not supported for this application type. Lex.Db.dll calls this API.
> Impact if not fixed: Using an API that is not part of the Windows SDK for Windows Store apps violates the Windows Store certification requirements.
> How to fix: Review the error messages to identify the API that is not part of the Windows SDK for Windows Store apps. Please note, C++ apps that are built in a debug configuration will fail this test even if it only uses APIs from the Windows SDK for Windows Store apps.

Any idea what is wrong there and how this problem can be sorted out? I tried google it but seems like there is very small help available for lex.db.

**UPDATE**:

I try using the old version of lex.db which is 1.1.4 and it works fine, may be some thing wrong with new version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a reference to an unsupported method which could be replaced with supported analogue.

At this moment the issue is already fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The Wack test tells you that: [You must use only the Windows Runtime APIs to implement the features of your Windows Store app](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694083.aspx#acr_3_1). Lex.db.dll does not run on all platforms and uses function from outside the windows runtime API. If it is your own dll you can rewrite to use the windows api.

This blog post on the lex.db set will give you some insights on what is going on and how to fix, [blog lex db](http://lexblog.azurewebsites.net/portable-usage-scenario-of-lex-db/).